# JQuery Undefined and $ Undefined Errors in Firefox 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, browser

I am doing some work for a client and their version of Firefox 4 is getting JQuery undefined errors, whereas my version of Firefox 4 is fine.  This is when viewing the exact same page (hosted online)!  Every other browser on both my machine and the clients is fine.

Does anyone have any thoughts as to why this could happen?  Could it be a caching issue?  Javascript is definitely enabled on the browser.

Edit:  Here is the log from the console where the jquery file load is attempted:

GET https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js [HTTP/1.0 200 Connection established 234ms]

Does 'connection established' mean that the file is loaded?  Or should I be expecting an 'OK' response?

Comment: have them clear their browser cache and then spin around in their chair twice and try again.

Comment: My friend is having a problem with his car. My car works, though. Any idea what the problem could be? :)

Comment: There's tons of code, and no clue as to where the problem is.

Comment: The code is a common denominator.  the browser also, so it has to be something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you loading a local copy of jQuery (instead of say a CDN) and this local copy is not in the client's computer?

Comment: So is it only a single page that breaks? Did the client try other browsers and only Firefox gives errors?

Comment: Web console shows that the JQuery file is being loaded correctly too.

Comment: Yes, other browsers are working fine for them.  Just firefox 4.  I would need to check regarding the other pages.

Comment: If anyone has a similar problem ... then the cause of this issue was that the jquery file wasn't being loaded on the clients network (I have no idea why).  The 'Connection Established' response in Firefox Web Console DOES NOT mean that the file has been retrieved.  Retrieved files have an OK response.  To get around it, I imported a copy of JQuery from the file system in addition to the one from google code.