# jQuery is not defined and could not find why

Tags: javascript, jquery

My jQuery code is not working and in Firebug console it says: "jQuery is not defined". I have checked jQuery is loading but I still not getting why its showing error.

My jQuery code looks like:

```
( function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$("form#add #divOptionsBlock .item img").css("visibility","hidden");

$('#divOptionsBlock .txtBoxStyle:first').change(function() {

    var fpath = $("#divOptionsBlock .item img").attr("src") ;

    var finalimage = 'http://shop.daactive.com/thumbnail.asp?file='+fpath+'&maxx=300&maxy=0';

    var fpath2 = $("form#add img#large").attr("src",finalimage);

    var imagepath_ahref="http://shop.daactive.com/"+fpath;
    var fpath3 = $("form#add a#listing_main_image_link").attr("href",imagepath_ahref);

    var fpath4 = $("form#add a#listing_main_image_link .MagicBoxShadow img").attr("src",imagepath_ahref);


    var textvalue = $('#divOptionsBlock .txtBoxStyle:first option:selected').text()
    $("#imagecaptiont").html(textvalue);


});
 });    
 } ) ( jQuery );
```

Comment: Could be the weird thing this asker was seeing especially if it's only in Firefox 4. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10605780/jquery-undefined-and-undefined-errors-in-firefox-4/10605914#10605914

Comment: Have you linked to the jQuery file?

Comment: Yes I have and its loading I have checked it in firebug NET

Comment: @Imran No, I don't think you have included jQuery.

Comment: I looked into your source code, and could not find jQuery. Could you tell me where you link to it? which line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not include jQuery! Add this to your `<head>` or before the end of `<body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are loading prototype.js (v 1.6.0.3) from http://shop.daactive.com/prototype.js and not jQuery.

To continue using prototype, you will need to refactor your javascript for the Prototype library and not the jQuery one: http://api.prototypejs.org/

If you choose to include jQuery too, you will need to use jQuery in its "safe" mode: 
http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

But this will mean loading 2 javascript libraries in and that can be a hefty chunk of javascript to load in, bearing page load times in mind.